# Something fishy with sms

Tags: sms

I am frequently getting a message at the bottom of my coolpad note 3 lite screen. It says "send sms". See the attached pic:

[image: screenshot]

I don't know what it is and whether it is sending something.
Pls help.

Comment: Probably a malware. Check your apps list if there is an unusual app.

Comment: That's a so-called "toast message". If it's caused by malware, it must either be a dumb dev (as usually toasts are explicitly created by apps) – or some security app gives you this notification (then again, dumb dev, for not mentioning the app). Checking your apps (especially for those you installed recently, before this activity started) cannot hurt, though.

Answer (score 0):

That is a 'toast' message which is executing from one of the apps that is currently running in your device.
Since this kind of errors are hard to exist in system apps, the app must be a non-system app.

Therefore go through the currently running apps in your device and remove non-system apps one by one until the message displaying stops (take precautions to save whatever the unsaved-changes in those apps before removing). That way you can find the causing app. You can disable it for the moment and report to the developers of it.

Thanks.